# Outlook is showing wrong contact's pictures

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We have a domain with a Public Address Book, and we are using Vcards.
Sometimes, contacts are being linked from the user's personal contact list to a public contact which results in his portrait instead the original contact.

eg.
We have Mike in the public contacts.
I have John in my personal contacts.
In the Public Contacts I see Mike with John's picture, and under 'linked contacts' I can see John's contact, taken from my personal contact list.

If I delete the linking it's ok, but the question is why does it happen and what can I do if a lot of users are suffering these, each with his own examples?

Comment: check if this is the case. [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-the-information-or-picture-for-a-contact-da2e7521-f6cb-4562-b97f-7551bac2d0c6)

Comment: Thank you @NWishAll ,
This is exactly the case and I know this solution, but I need something global as currently I'm loging into each user who has this problem and unlinking manually.
I'm also looking for the reason this happens in order to avoid it completely.